# Windows 7 changes my uefi default boot when it starts

Tags: windows-7, linux, grub, uefi, bcd

I installed Windows 7 in a HP Compaq 6300. First I disabled secure boot and enabled legacy mode. Then I installed Ubuntu in other partition. Ubuntu detected some uefi partitions and let me create / and /home. When i restart the computer, it shows me the grub menu and if i select ubuntu or windows it works.
But when i restart windows, the grub menu disapears. If i go to the boot menu it only shows me in UEFI boot sources a lot of Windows Boot Manager, but not the ubuntu boot. 
I can recover the grub if I go to the Run UEFI application option in the boot menu and select the /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi. It starts ubuntu and I can recover with grub-install /dev/sda

I have tried easyBCD and Visual BCD Editor to use the Windows Boot menu to start ubuntu, but I can't do it with UEFI.

Is there any way to forbid Windows 7 to change the UEFI boot order?

Thanks.